# MySql get rows between date values

Tags: sql, mysql, date

I'm doing the following query and getting all rows returned, regardless of date:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT p.name, p.category, u.f_name, t.name
 FROM   (
        prizes p, tags t, results r
        )
 LEFT JOIN
        users u
 ON     (r.user_id = u.id)
 LEFT JOIN
        f_tag_lookup tl
 ON     (tl.tag_id = t.id)
 WHERE  r.tag_id = t.id
        AND r.date BETWEEN concat(date_format(LAST_DAY(now() - interval 1 month), '%Y-%m-'),'01') AND last_day(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

`r.date` is a datetime field. there are three rows with dates from last month and three rows with dates from this month but I'm getting all rows back?

Would appreciate any pointers. I want to return results between the first and last day of last month i.e. all results for July.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out. The SQL regarding dates was fine but the JOINS were wrong. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 3):

Could you not just use the month() date function ?

e.g. use month(date) = month(now()) as the filter.

You would need to also match on year(date) = year(now()), if you had data from more than one year.

I'm not sure of the performance, but it seems more readable to me to express it that way.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.name, p.category, u.f_name, t.name
FROM (prizes p, tags t, results r)
LEFT JOIN users u ON (r.user_id = u.id)
LEFT JOIN f_tag_lookup tl ON (tl.tag_id = t.id)
WHERE r.tag_id = t.id AND 
      month(r.date) = month(now()) AND 
      year(r.date) = year(now())
```

Comment: MONTH(r.date) = 07 and Year(r.date) = 2009 can't be worse in performance than r.date BETWEEN concat(date_format(LAST_DAY(now() -interval 1 month),'%Y-%m-'),'01') AND last_day(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

Comment: perhaps not, but the use between operator, against a constant uper bound might be more optimal for indexed selection

Comment: thanks for the answers. So I would do month(now() - interval 1 month) for the previous month?